# Solving a system of three linear equations to find $\dfrac{x_0y_0 + y_0z_0 + z_0x_0}{4(x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

> Let $x_0,y_o,z_0 \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$. If ${x_0,y_0,z_0}$ is the solution of the system of equations $$x+y-2z=0 \tag{1}$$ $$2x-3y+z=0 \tag{2}$$ $$x-5y+4z=k, k \in \mathbb{R} \tag{3}$$ then what is the value of $\dfrac{x_0y_0 + y_0z_0 + z_0x_0}{4(x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2)}$?

The answer is a **single digit integer** ranging from $0$ to $9$, both inclusive.

---

**My attempt:**

Multiplying $(1)$ by $5$ and adding to $(3)$

$$x-z=k/6$$

Multiplying $(1)$ by $3$ and adding to $(2)$

$$x-z=0$$ $$\implies k/6=0$$ $$\implies k = 0$$

We can then solve the system of equations to get

$$x=y=z=t\text{ (say)}$$

Now, $$\dfrac{x_0y_0 + y_0z_0 + z_0x_0}{4(x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2)} = \dfrac{t\cdot t + t\cdot t + t \cdot t}{4(t^2+t^2+t^2)} = \dfrac{3t^2}{4\cdot 3t^2} = \dfrac{1}{4}$$

---

I can't find any obvious errors in this solution, yet $\dfrac{1}{4}$ is not a valid answer as it isn't a single digit integer.

Is there a mistake in my reasoning, or is there something wrong with the question?

Comment: Your solution looks correct (at least to me).

Comment: Won't you get $t=0$?

Comment: @razivo Why do you think so? As far as I can tell, once $x=y=z$, $t$ can be any value. Also, it's given that $x_0, y_0, z_0 \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$

Comment: Well, you have a homogenous system of equations so $x=y=z=0$ must be a solution.

Comment: @razivo But that case is explicitly forbidden in the question so that the expression doesn't have an indeterminate value.

Comment: Since it looks like $k$ is supposed to be a parameter that can take an arbitrary real value, it seems odd that it has to be zero for there to be a solution. This suggests there is something wrong with the question (at least as given here).